# Switching proxy in python (using urllib)

Tags: python

I want to allow proxy switching in runtime. My (ugly) code is:

```
import urllib.request
proxydict={'http':'http://45.63.66.17:8080'}
proxydict2={'http':'http://3.212.39.212:80'}
proxy_support1 = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxydict)
opener1 = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support1)
proxy_support2 = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxydict2)
opener2 = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support2)
print(opener1.open('http://icanhazip.com').read())
print(opener2.open('http://icanhazip.com').read())
```

However, it can not work well. (I'd check that the proxy are online.) How can it be done in python? Does there exist a more elegant way?

Comment: as for me problem is proxy which may not work as you expect. I would only use `open(... , timeout=3)` to close connection after (ie.) 3 seconds.

Comment: @furas I just find myself pretty lack of knowledge of using proxy. If I don't use `timeout`, then after execute `read()`, the connection to the proxy server would still exists? And if the proxy server is offline, then it will throw a exception error?